# Storing multiple-inheritance objects in container

Tags: c++, oop

A library I use has many types, all of which derive from the same 2 interfaces:

```
class Huey : public IDuck, public ICartoonCharacter
{
...
};

class Dewey : public IDuck, public ICartoonCharacter
{
...
};

class Louie : public IDuck, public ICartoonCharacter
{
...
};
```

I'd like to store objects of all the above types in a wrapper class and stick objects of that wrapper class in a container. Of course I should be able to call methods belonging to both interfaces from my wrapper class.

What are my options here? I could think of

- storing `IDuck *`s in my wrapper and dynamic_cast-ing to `ICartoonCharacter`, or
- using something like `boost::any` while making my wrapper a class-template, with a couple of `static_asserts` to ensure the template parameter inherits from `IDuck` and `ICartoonCharacter`.

but neither option particularly appeals. Any ideas?

[two interfaces, multiple inheritance combine into one container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186380/two-interfaces-multiple-inheritance-combine-into-one-container) is a related question, but James Kanze's answer doesn't work for me, as I can't change the 3 classes.

EDIT: Don't use multiple inheritance often, had forgotten syntax. Now inheriting `public`ly from both interfaces.

EDIT: Now using dynamic_cast instead of static_cast (which won't work).

EDIT: I found both Mike Seymour's and Matthieu M's answers promising. I'll accept one of their answers once I've coded it all up. Thanks!

Comment: You can't static_cast from `IDuck*` to the unrelated type `ICartoonCharacter*`. You could dynamic_cast provided `IDuck` has at least one virtual function.

Comment: I usually use the first option, if using `dynamic_cast` is possible  (see @SteveJessop comment above).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think even if your children classes cannot be changed to inherit from a single parent (who in turn inherits from both current parents,) you can still benefit from introducing such a class (e.g. `ICartoonDuck`.) Your can store `ICartoonDuck`s in your container and worry less about memory layout problems. (You still need unsafe casts though; this is still a hack.)

Comment: @yzt - that's an idea, if all classes inherit `IDuck` and `ICartoonCharacter`. Otherwise, it would impossible (unless interfaces are terribly mixed)

Comment: @Ambarish Sridharanarayanan - is the second inheritance still `public`? Or `public` keyword is really missing (meaning - private inheritance)?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Yeah, if all the inheritance scopes and orders are the same, having the `ICartoonDuck` class would help the *client* code to be mostly free of unsafe casts and only the container class needs to have unsafe constructs (along with some compile-time and runtime checks to assure safety as much as possible.)

Comment: @KirilKirov: oops, yes, they're all public inheritance.

Comment: @SteveJessop: doh, I'd have to use dynamic_cast, or in the absence of RTTI, reinterpret_cast, yes.

Comment: @AmbarishSridharanarayanan: `reinterpret_cast` doesn't do it. It will compile but because of the multiple inheritance it can give the wrong answer. The only thing that potentially might make it work is if the empty base class optimization means the `IDuck` and `ICartoonCharacter` base class sub-objects have the same address, but this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple option is to store two pointers in the wrapper:

```
struct CartoonDuckWrapper {
    IDuck * duck;
    ICartoonCharacter * toon;

    template <class CartoonDuck>
    CartoonDuckWrapper(CartoonDuck & cd) : duck(&cd), toon(&cd) {}
};
```

There's no particular need to use `static_assert` to check that `CartoonDuck` inherits from both base classes, although that might give slightly better diagnostics than simply letting the pointer conversions fail.

If the base classes are polymorphic (which, being interfaces, they probably are), you could save the space of one pointer, in exchange for a run-time cost, by using `dynamic_cast` to convert one to the other. `static_cast` can't be used for such a "cross-cast" between base classes.

Answer (score 3):

As all issues in programming, you can solve it by adding one more level of indirection.

```
class ICartoonDuck: public IDuck, public ICartoonCharacter {};

template <typename T>
class CartoonDuck: public ICartoonDuck {
public:
    explicit CartoonDuck(T t): _t(std::move(t)) {}

    // IDuck interface
    virtual void foo() override { t.foo(); }

    // ICartoonCharacter interface
    virtual void bar() override { t.bar(); }

private:
    T _t; // or any ownership scheme that makes sense
}; // class CartoonDuck

template <typename T>
CartoonDuck<T> makeCartoonDuck(T t) { return CartoonDuck(std::move(t)); }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<CartoonDuck<T>> makeUniqueCartoonDuck(Args&&...) {
    return std::unique_ptr<CartoonDuck<T>>(new T(std::forward<Args>()...);
}
```

Now, you can happily store `std::unique_ptr<ICartoonDuck>` in your container.

This can be used as:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ICartoonDuck>> cartoonDucks;
cartoonDucks.push_back(makeUniqueCartoonDuck<Huey>());
cartoonDucks.push_back(makeUniqueCartoonDuck<Dewey>());
cartoonDucks.push_back(makeUniqueCartoonDuck<Louie>());

for (std::unique_ptr<ICartoonDuck> const& cd: cartoonDucks) {
    cd->foo();
    cd->bar();
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly `Cartoon Duck` will hold `Huey` `louie` etc right?

Comment: @Koushik: Yes, that is the idea, let me make an example as apparently it's not as obvious as I thought it would be.

Comment: i like this solution as it feels like the idimatic c++ ways.+1

Comment: @Koushik: it is more "object-oriented" maybe, but I feel obligated to mention that Mike's implementation does not requires another allocation (though it does not handle ownership, either); so really it's a matter of requirements/fine-tuning :)

Answer (score 2):

Create an intermediate class:

```
class ILuckyDuck: public IDuck, ICartoonCharacter //...
```

with:

```
class Huey : public ILuckyDuck //...
```

*etc*, and store:

```
std::vector<std:shared_ptr<ILuckyDuck>> donald;
```

Comment: But `Huey` isn't an `ILuckyDuck`, so this doesn't help.

Comment: But the questioner has specifically stated that he cannot alter the class `Huey`, so this still doesn't help.

Comment: I'd go for this too, but correct: `std::vector<std:shared_ptr<ILuckyDuck *>>` `->` `std::vector<std:shared_ptr<ILuckyDuck>>`